# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController':

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting below error while creating a spring maven rest services:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcUserDAO': No qualifying bean of type [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO] found for dependency [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO] found for dependency [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Jan 05, 2019 6:17:28 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcUserDAO': No qualifying bean of type [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO] found for dependency [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO] found for dependency [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO] found for dependency [com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
```

Here is my code:

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcUserDAO jdbcUserDAO;    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
    }
}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
public interface UserDAO {
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

**jdbcUserDAo.java**

```
public class JdbcUserDAO implements UserDAO {

    DataSource dataSource;  
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        String sql = "select * from customer";
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        System.out.println("getJdbcTemplate() "+jdbcTemplate);
        List<User> userList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
        return userList;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService" />
<import resource="classpath:/application-config.xml" /> 


</beans>
```

**application-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"


xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="jdbcUserDAO" class="com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

 <!--   <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>     -->

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****"></property>
    <property name="username" value="***"></property>
    <property name="password" value="***"></property>
   </bean>




</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please advise what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `@Service` or `@Repository` annotation top of `@Service public class JdbcUserDAO implements UserDAO {}`

Comment: You have already configured/wired the bean `jdbcUserDAO` in the `application-config.xml` file, then why are you using `@Autowired`? if you intend to use `@Autowired` then mark the `jdbcUserDAO` as `@Repository`

Comment: You should always check the exception's `Caused by` part, because it tells you what's wrong. In this case it tells `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and `No qualifying bean of type com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO` means this bean cannot be found.

Comment: When I removed `@Autowired` from `jdbcUserDAO`, then I get following error`IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [/application-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/application-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. Can you please suggest what should be the classpath of file stored in `src/main/resources` folder